# How can this string can print

Tags: c, arrays

I am a newbie. I was doing some experiments in arrays. I tried this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char arr[7] = "Network";
    printf("%s\n", arr);
    return 0;
}
```

**output :** Network

Also I tried this,

```
int main()
{
    char arr[7] = "Its time to work";
    printf("%s\n", arr);
    return 0;
}
```

**warning: initializer-string for array of chars is too long [enabled by default]**

output :** Its tim

I have this version of gcc -v
**gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3)**

Why in the first place there was no warning? Why it gave me output 'Network' in place of garbage or 'Networ', if '%s' appends '\0' in the end in second case?

Comment: Undefined Behavior.

Comment: Because the array contains the first 7 `char`s, which are 'N', 'e', 't', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'k'.  What's missing is the terminating null... so printing it like that is actually undefined behaviour and could have crashed or who knows what... but you probably lucked out and had a null byte following the array (by chance).  (It's only undefined behaviour because `printf()` will access past the end of the array... if you printed differently and avoided that problem, it'd be fine).

Comment: To print only up to 7 characters from a _string_ use `printf("%.7s\n", arr);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both of your examples, you are using *string literals* as initializers for your character arrays.  Although it is implicit, a string literal is always appended with a null character.

C99, n1570 *[(downloadable here)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)* section 6.4.5 String literals, para. 6 says:

> In translation phase 7, a byte or code of value zero is appended to
>   each multibyte character sequence that results from a string literal
>   or literals.

Furthermore, (credit to @Olaf) in section *6.7.9 Initialization, para. 14* it says:

> An array of character type may be initialized by a character string
>   literal or UTF−8 string literal, optionally enclosed in braces.
>   Successive bytes of the string literal (including the terminating null
>   character ***if there is room*** or if the array is of unknown size)
>   initialize the elements of the array.  [***emphasis*** mine]

The take away is, even though it is not apparent, the string literal initializer `"Network"` contains 8 characters, while the variable `arr` has only space for 7:

```
"Network"   ->  |N|e|t|w|o|r|k|0|  
char arr[7] ->  | | | | | | | |
```

Because your statement:

```
 char arr[7] = "Network";
```

does not provide enough space in `arr`, it creates an array of `char`, it *does not create a string*.  Using it as a string will result in *[undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)*.  i.e. anything can happen.

Comment: but i have never saw undefined behaviour. I can always print 'Network'.

Comment: Yes, you did see undefined behavior. One aspect of undefined behavior is that you might accidentally get what you expected to get.

Comment: @acidlategamer Also note that the second snippet is not correct C. GCC rejects it when `-pedantic-errors` is used.

Comment: The line you cite does not invoke undefined behaviour. It is well defined.

Comment: And there is no `NULL` terminator. `NULL` is a macro with a _null pointer constant_, something completely unrelated.

Comment: -pedantic-errors I read about it. It says to use when there are undefined behaviour. In first case there is no error even if I use it. Second case itself gives warnings that may be converted into errors if I want, so -pedantic-errors is of no use in undefined behaviour here in first case.

Comment: The declaration `char arr[7] = "Network";` is well defined, Treating the contents of `arr` as a string is not.

Comment: @ryyker: Please read the standard. You concentrate on the wrong part of the code. The initialiser is completely legal. (whether it **should be** is disputable, it is a legacy which should have been cut out at least with C11)

Comment: 1) There is no 8th `char`, neither owned by `arr` or otherwise (actually there are no objects beyond those defined or dynamically allocated). 2) "In C, freedom to write outside ..." - The code does not write anywhere. 3) "... the specification" - which specification? 4) There still is no `NULL` terminator.

Comment: @Olaf -  I appreciate your perspectives.  Although they are mostly very precise, they are not always very accurate.  I think you are missing my intended message by focusing on the imprecision of my word choices.  The message is simply that treating `arr` as a string, (eg. by using it with any of the string functions, or with `printf` can lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: I indeed criticise your choise of words. Not only because they are imprecise, but in fact missleading. While for experts it is clear, such quetstions are asked by beginners. The language should be clear and stick as much to common nomenclature as possible (and reasonable for a beginner). Please remember other beginners will read this, too. They will missintepret this text.

Comment: Replacing write by assign is still wrong. There is no assignment either, and the initialiser is correct as we figured out by now. The UB stems from **reading** _here_.

Comment: @Olaf - I have re-written my answer to address the issues you have pointed out.  I would appreciate your response.  Thank you.

Comment: @ryyker: I removed the DV, it is acceptable now for me. Thanks for clarifying. Just one last thing: It would be good to point out why the 8-character literal still gets copied to the array. After all the literal itself will not make it's way intot the program, it is just used to copy it into the array. The cited section is not relevant here. 6.7.9p14 is the parapgraph you need. Oh, and you should use the final draft (n1570) as reference; it is the same as the standard except for two macros not relevant for discussions.

Comment: @Olaf -  I will address the additional items you suggest in my post once I have a few minutes to look at the reference.  I will text you when I do.  And thank you for your persistence.

Comment: @Olaf - I looked up the paragraph you cited, and yes, it is very relevant here.  I updated answer to include it, with credit to you.  Great help.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

based on my learning from this thread

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char arr[7] = "Network";
    //printf("%s\n", arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Is a valid program. Printing with %s is not. It should be seen as a character array.

```
int main()
{
    char arr[7] = "Its time to work";
    printf("%s\n", arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Is a wrong program as its the programmer's responsibility to check the size of array when assigning any value.

Comment: _Is a valid program..._    Well, yes it is valid, it will compile, but it does contain potential for undefined behavior. What I said above still applies.